# PHP SOAP:How to get param inside xml header and body tag

Tags: php, xml, soap, nameservers, soapheader

In PHP I need to create a soap-xml request like

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:NS1="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherBase" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS1:TAuthenticationHeader xsi:type="NS1:TAuthenticationHeader">
    <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">user</UserName>
    <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">pass</Password>
    </NS1:TAuthenticationHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS2:ExecuteRequest xmlns:NS2="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherCustomLink-ICustomLinkSoap">
    <ARequest xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?> <EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime Type="TEoCustomLinkRequestDateTime"></EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime>
    </ARequest>
    </NS2:ExecuteRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the problem is to get param  in the header (like xmlns:NS1...) and body (like xmlns:NS2...) tags
With my script I get NS1 and NS2 swapped in the first tag after header and body. results in `<NS1:TAuthenticationHeader>` .... and . `</NS2:ExecuteRequest>`

My php script:

```
<?php

$wsdl_url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/wsdl/ICustomLinkSoap';
$location = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/soap/ICustomLinkSoap';
$action = 'ExecuteRequest';
$version = SOAP_1_1;
$one_way = 0;


$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array(
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'         => true,
    'encoding'  => 'ISO-8859-1',
    'exceptions'    => true,

));

$auth = (object)array(
        'UserName'=>'xxxx',
        'Password'=>'yyyy'
        );
$header = new SoapHeader($wsdl_url,'TAuthenticationHeader',$auth,false);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$request1  = '
<ARequest>
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?&gt;

        &lt;EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime Type="TEoCustomLinkRequestDateTime" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="GdxEoStructures.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;

        &lt;/EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime&gt;</ARequest>
';

$xmlVar = new SoapVar($request1, XSD_ANYXML);

$result = $soapClient->__SoapCall(
    'ExecuteRequest',
    array($xmlVar)
);

// show result in xml-file
$f = fopen("./soap-request2.xml", "w");
xx = serialize($soapClient->__getLastRequest());
fwrite($f, $xx);

?>
```

Result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherCustomLink-ICustomLinkSoap" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy/wsdl/ICustomLinkSoap" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:TAuthenticationHeader>
            <UserName>xxxx</UserName>
            <Password>yyyy</Password>
        </ns2:TAuthenticationHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ExecuteRequest>
            <ARequest>
            &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?&gt;
        &lt;EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime Type="TEoCustomLinkRequestDateTime" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="GdxEoStructures.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;
        &lt;/EoCustomLinkRequestDateTime&gt;
        </ARequest>
        </ns1:ExecuteRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help to how to do so?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is to get param in the header (like xmlns:NS1...) and
>   body (like xmlns:NS2...) tags With my script I get NS1 and NS2 swapped
>   in the first tag after header and body. results in
>    .... and .

It's not a problem, because swapped not only namespaces of elements but also its definitions at the head of SOAP-ENV:Envelope

Your first xml

```
xmlns:NS1="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherBase"
xmlns:NS2="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherCustomLink-ICustomLinkSoap"
```

Compare with generated by php

```
xmlns:ns1="urn:UCoSoapDispatcherCustomLink-ICustomLinkSoap" 
xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy/wsdl/ICustomLinkSoap"
```